# Bash and Dash inconsistently check command substitution error codes with `errexit`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dash-shell

I seem to have encountered a very, very strange inconsistency in the way both `dash` and `bash` check for error conditions with the `errexit` option.

Using both `dash` and `bash` *without* the `set -e`/`set -o errexit` option, the following program:

```
foo()
{
    echo pre
    bar=$(fail)
    echo post
}

foo
```

will print the following (with slightly different error strings for `dash`):

```
pre
./foo.sh: line 4: fail: command not found
post
```

*With* the `errexit` option, it will print the following:

```
pre
./foo.sh: line 4: fail: command not found
```

Surprisingly, however, if `bar` is `local`, the program will always `echo` both `pre` and `post`. More specifically, using both `dash` and `bash` *with our without* the `errexit` option, the following program:

```
foo()
{
    echo pre
    local bar=$(fail)
    echo post
}

foo
```

will print the following:

```
pre
./foo.sh: line 4: fail: command not found
post
```

In other words, it seems that the return value of a command substitution that is assigned to a local variable is not checked by `errexit`, but it is if the variable is global.

I would have been inclined to think this was simply a corner case bug, if it didn't happen with both shells. Since `dash` is specifically designed to be POSIX conformant I wonder if this behavior is actually specified by the POSIX standard, though I have a hard time imagining how that would make sense.

`dash(1)` has this to say about `errexit`:

> If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails. The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested if the command is used to control an `if`, `elif`, `while`, or `until`; or if the command is the left hand operand of an “&&” or “||” operator.

`bash(1)` is somewhat more verbose, but I have a hard time making sense of it:

> Exit immediately if a `pipeline` (which may consist of a single `simple command`), a `list`, or a `compound command` (see `SHELL GRAMMAR` above), exits with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with `!`. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while `-e` was being ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on `ERR`, if set, is executed before the shell exits. This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see `COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT` above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where `-e` is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the `-e` setting, even if `-e` is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets `-e` while executing in a context where `-e` is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.

Comment: [Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) warns about [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155) and other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR The exit status of `local` "hides" the exit status of any command substitutions appearing in one of its arguments.

---

The exit status of a variable assignment is poorly documented (or at least, I couldn't find any specifics in a quick skim of the various man pages and the POSIX spec). As far as I can tell, the exit status is taken as the exit status of the *last* command substitution that occurs in the value of the assignment, or 0 if there are no command substitutions. Non-final command substitutions appear to be included in the list of "tested" situations, as an assignment like

```
foo=$(false)$(true)
```

does not exit with `errexit` set.

`local`, however, is a command itself whose exit status is normally 0, independent of any command substitutions that occur in its arguments. That is, while

```
foo=$(false)
```

has an exit status of 1,

```
local foo=$(false)
```

will have an exit status of 0, with any command substitutions in an argument seemingly considered "tested" for the purposes of `errexit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

foo()
{
    echo pre
    local bar
    bar=$(fail)
    echo post
}

foo

exit
```

!! OR !!

```
#!/bin/bash

foo()
{
    set -e
    echo pre
    local bar
    bar=$(fail)
    echo post
}

foo

exit
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./errexit_function 
pre
./errexit_function: line 8: fail: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is a work around for a bug in bash, but try this,

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

foo()
{
    echo true || return_value=$?
    echo the command returned a value of ${return_value:-0}
    $(fail) || return_value=$?
    echo the command returned a value of ${return_value:-0}
    echo post
}

foo

exit
```